# Racket: custodian-limit-memory not raising out-of-memory error?

Tags: memory-management, error-handling, racket

I'm trying to use custodians in Racket to set a limit to memory usage within a given scope and raise an out-of-memory error if it exceeds that limit.

Following examples for how to use custodians, I put together this simple program:

```
#lang racket/base

(with-handlers
  ([exn:fail:out-of-memory? (λ (err)
    (println "Caught out-of-memory error! :D"))])
  
  (parameterize ([current-custodian (make-custodian)])
    (custodian-limit-memory (current-custodian) (* 2 1024 1024))
    (make-bytes (* 4 1024 1024)))
  (println "Should have raised OoM. :("))
```

I expect to see the output "Caught out-of-memory error! :D", but instead I am seeing "Should have raised OoM. :(".

Any idea why my code isn't raising the out-of-memory error when I call `make-bytes` here?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will help you somehow, but here is another [issue caused by (make-custodian)](https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/3782). Your code works (= catches memory error) when you remove `(parameterize ([current-custodian (make-custodian)])`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of removing `(parameterize ([current-custodian (make-custodian)])`, but it still isn't working for me. If that works for you though, could be something wrong with how I am invoking Racket? (I'm running the program via `racket path/to/my-program.rkt`)